# can't clone repo from remote - ssh keys identification error

Tags: git, ssh

I'm on Windows and I'm using Git Bash. I want to clone remote bare repository. Supposedly I've set up ssh keys correctly, because I can access server through ssh protocol. I've tested it by trying to get a list of directories on server:

```
$ ssh user@servername.com ls
```

It asks for passphrase:

```
Enter passphrase for key 'c/users/user/.ssh/id_rsa'
```

I type it in and successfuly get the listing of directories.
However, if I try to clone repository through ssh it fails. I write the following in Git Bash:

```
$ git clone ssh://user@servername.com:80/path/to/repo.git
```

And get the following error:

```
ssh_exchange_identification: Connection closed by remote host
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
```

Is it the problem with ssh keys? Or it could be something else since I've tested my keys work?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

```
git clone ssh://user@servername.com:/path/to/repo.git
```

It is unlikely the ssh daemon will be listening on port 80.
It would listen on the default port (22).

Comment: based on how you ssh - you want to use the same port, so since your $ ssh user@servername.com ls works then git clone ssh://user@servername.com:/path/to/repo.git should work also